# El método setEditable(true) no me habilita la edición del textArea

Tags: java, java-swing

El método setEditale(true), no me habilita la edición del textArea cuando hago click en el botón nuevo, anexo código, los demás elementos si los  habilita para la edición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
----> txtNota.setEditable(true);

```
 private void btnNuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //Habilita los botones
    btnPrimero.setEnabled(false);
    btnAnterior.setEnabled(false);
    btnSiguiente.setEnabled(false);
    btnUltimo.setEnabled(false);
    btnNuevo.setEnabled(false);
    btnModificar.setEnabled(false);
    btnBorrar.setEnabled(false);
    btnBuscar.setEnabled(false);
    btnGuardar.setEnabled(true);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);

    //Habilita campos
    txtIDProducto.setEditable(true);
    txtDescripcion.setEditable(true);
    txtPrecio.setEditable(true);
    txtNota.setEditable(true);
    cmbIVA.setEditable(true);

    //Limpiar campos
    txtIDProducto.setText("");
    txtDescripcion.setText("");
    txtPrecio.setText("");
    txtNota.setText("");
    cmbIVA.setSelectedIndex(0);

    //Activamos el flag de registro nuevo
    nuevo = true;

    //Damos foco al campo ID
    txtIDProducto.requestFocusInWindow();

}
```

Comment: Convendría que mostraras el código donde creas y añades `txtNota` al panel.

Comment: El txtNota lo agrego desde los objetos graficos, no desde código, el código que anexo es para habilitar y deshabilitar la edición si el registro es se va a agregar o se va ha modificar.

Comment: Bueno pero `txtNota` es un objeto como cualquier otro. Nadie sabe si le estás dando unos atributos que impiden que éste sea editable.

Comment: Yo sí que atributos le doy o no le doy a mis objetos, creo que su respuesta no es nada asertiva.

Comment: ¿asertiva? Vamos a ver, si quieres que se te ayude debes indicar dónde creas el objeto en cuestión. Si dices que lo estás haciendo editable y no funciona es de suponer que algo estás haciendo mal en el objeto o que te estás equivocando de objeto. No entiendo tu comentario cuando lo que se pretende es ayudarte.